# What exactly does it mean to “kill” a character’s past?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

In Enter the Gungeon, you play as a character who enters the “Gungeon” in search of the bullet and gun which can kill their past.

What does “killing” the past mean exactly? Upon successfully achieving it in the game, you play through a scene in the character’s past. Does this mean that you are changing the past? Or is it about helping the character come to terms with what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given EtG's obsession with guns, I interpret it very literally. You're quite literally killing the sequence of events in the past that caused the character to enter the Gungeon to begin with. This is in line with the intro cinematic:

> ...some who hear the legend would risk everything for another shot. To claim their prize and make what was done, undone...

Comment: If the sequence of events are killed, what are they replaced with?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Like, how to resolve the paradox of "characters that kill their past will never need to enter the dungeon and kill their past?" Realistically I'd say the devs probably handwave it but my personal interpretation is EtG uses Many Worlds for their time travel. Some people have interpreted Pilot's reply "Another time" in his past kill to mean he picked up his skills in another time(line) in support of this interpretation.

Comment: Taking the Pilot's past as an example, what does killing his past mean? Does it mean that now he never was in the situation where he was caught stealing with his friend? Or is the actual past that he left his friend to die and 'killing" his past replaces it with the version that he stayed and fought to protect his friend?

Comment: I can't find any evidence that there's not room for both interpretations within canon.